# r - Extract Values from Statistical Objects in List to Vector

Tags: r, list, object, extract

I have list of statistical objects from which I would like extract p-values.

The question is similar to the results of this function:

```
ls.stests <- apply(mtcars, 2, shapiro.test)
```

I would like to end up with is vector resembling (preferably without using a loop, but hey):

```
0.1229, 6.058e-06, 0.02081...
```

I have tried the following:

```
ls.stests[[1:14]$p.value], ls.stests[[, "p.value"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is always better to check the `str`ucture before doing any extraction

```
 str(ls.stests)
List of 11
 $ mpg :List of 4
  ..$ statistic: Named num 0.948
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "W"
  ..$ p.value  : num 0.123
  ..$ method   : chr "Shapiro-Wilk normality test"
  ..$ data.name: chr "newX[, i]"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
 $ cyl :List of 4
  ..$ statistic: Named num 0.753
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "W"
  ..$ p.value  : num 0.00000606
  ..$ method   : chr "Shapiro-Wilk normality test"
  ..$ data.name: chr "newX[, i]"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
 $ disp:List of 4
...
```

From the `str`ucture, it is evidents that it is a `list` of `list` i.e. the outer list is for the columns from the `apply` and the inner nested `list` from the output of `shapiro.test`

So, we loop over the `list` with one of the `*apply` functions i.e. `sapply`, and extract the `p.value` from the `list` output of 'shapiro.test'

```
sapply(ls.stests, function(x) x$p.value)
```

-output

```
        mpg              cyl             disp               hp             drat               wt             qsec               vs 
0.12288135853944 0.00000605833813 0.02080656961086 0.04880823810517 0.11006075742668 0.09265498889321 0.59351764929516 0.00000009737376 
              am             gear             carb 
0.00000007836354 0.00001306843765 0.00043824049593
```

---

We may also do this in a single step

```
apply(mtcars, 2, function(x) shapiro.test(x)$p.value)
             mpg              cyl             disp               hp             drat               wt             qsec               vs 
0.12288135853944 0.00000605833813 0.02080656961086 0.04880823810517 0.11006075742668 0.09265498889321 0.59351764929516 0.00000009737376 
              am             gear             carb 
0.00000007836354 0.00001306843765 0.00043824049593
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
     summarise(across(everything(), ~ shapiro.test(.)$p.value))
#        mpg            cyl       disp         hp      drat         wt      qsec               vs               am          gear         carb
#1 0.1228814 0.000006058338 0.02080657 0.04880824 0.1100608 0.09265499 0.5935176 0.00000009737376 0.00000007836354 0.00001306844 0.0004382405
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `map_df` and `tidy()`:

```
library(purrr)
map(mtcars, shapiro.test) %>% 
  keep(~ .x$p.value > 0.05) %>% 
  map_df(broom::tidy)
```

Output:

```
  statistic p.value method                     
      <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                      
1     0.948  0.123  Shapiro-Wilk normality test
2     0.946  0.110  Shapiro-Wilk normality test
3     0.943  0.0927 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
4     0.973  0.594  Shapiro-Wilk normality test
```